# Differentiation of a composite function

Tags: calculus

Let $$f(x)=g(2 \sin(x)h(x)),$$ where $g'(0)=3$ and $h(0)=3$. What is the value of $f'(0)$?
I solved this and my answer is $18$. But someone told me that this is not correct. Any help?

Comment: your answer is correct, $f'(x)=(2\cos (x) h(x)+2\sin (x) h'(x))g'(2\sin (x)h(x))$

Comment: ok,i have the same,is it answer 18?

Comment: yes, $f'(0)=(2.1.h(0)+0)g'(0)=2.3.3=18$

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. We have $f'(x)=g'\big(2\sin (x)h(x)\big)\big(2\cos (x) h(x)+2\sin (x) h'(x)\big)$. Now using basic arithmetic and the fact that $g'(0)=h(0)=3$, we come to $f'(0)=18$.